# Rename list of files by removing and substituting components

Tags: r, rename

I am trying to rename a very long list of .wav files contained within a folder. The files are currently named as follows:

SNR_-10_ieee21m01.wav

SNR_-10_ieee21m02.wav

SNR_-10_ieee21m03.wav... etc.

I would like to remove the 'SNR_' and 'ieee', as well as substituting the 'm' for an underscore, so that they read as follows:

-10_21_01.wav

-10_21_02.wav

-10_21_03.wav.... etc.

I started by trying to use the 'file.rename' function to substitute the 'm' for '_', but I can't even get this first step right - it's throwing up lots of 'FALSE' text in the R console.

```
startingDir <- "C:/Users/Desktop/-10"

files <- list.files(startingDir,pattern="*.wav", full.names=T)
sapply(files,FUN=function(eachPath){
  file.rename(from=eachPath,to=sub(pattern="m",replacement="_",eachPath))
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to capture the 3 numbers of interest, and use them to create your new file names.

This is what it looks like:

```r
# Your strings
str <- c("SNR_-10_ieee21m01.wav", "SNR_-10_ieee21m02.wav")

# Note the parenthesis to capture the 3 groups
# and the use of \\1, \\2 and \\3 to insert them in the replacement
fixed_str <- gsub(
   pattern = "SNR_(\\-?[0-9]+)_ieee([0-9]+)m([0-9]+)\\.wav$",
   replacement = "\\1_\\2_\\3.wav", 
   str)
```

EDIT: Now the first group captures the (optional) minus sign.

Then just apply that to your files. Your use of `apply` is fine, but I am partial to the `purrr` package which provides all sorts of map functions. `walk` is just like `map` but does not capture the result. It is useful to run functions for their side effects, like `rename_file`.

```r
rename_file <- function(fi) {
  new_fi <- gsub(pattern = "SNR_(\\-?[0-9]+)_ieee([0-9]+)m([0-9]+)\\.wav$", 
                   replacement = "\\1_\\2_\\3.wav",
                   fi)
  file.rename(from = fi, to = new_fi)
}

library("purrr")
walk(files, rename_file)
```

Comment: Thank you, Antoine-sac. This looks to be doing what I want. However, when I run the above code using 'map(startingDir, rename_file)' I get a '[[1]] [1] FALSE' reading on the console and the files in the folder that is set to 'startingDir' remain the same. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You want to apply `rename_file` to each file, hence the call should be `map(files, rename_file)` where `files` contains the full file names.

Comment: Using `walk` instead of `map` will get rid of the console output. You may want to add some logging in rename_file though, to keep track of what is getting renamed.

Comment: I see. But is there a way that I can apply this rename rule to an entire folder of files currently saved on my desktop and create a new folder with the changed names (or indeed simply replace the old names with the new ones in the existing folder)? Rather than individually inputting every current file name (if I've understood you correctly)...

Comment: Well that's what `list.files` is for. I was assuming `files = list.files(...)` as in the code you posted. If you'd rather change the function to take a directory path, that's fine as well. You'll still have to call `fi = list.files(path)` in the body of the function. Just to be clear, you do NOT have to process the files by hand one by one and my answer does not suggest that.

Comment: Thank you for your help, antoine-sac. Much appreciated. As I suspected might have been the case, I misunderstood your comment above.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: Sorry Antoine-sac, something that I have just noticed - running the above code removes the minus ('-') sign from the first number. For example, the file becomes 10_21_01.wav instead of -10_21_01.wav. Is there a way that I can retain this?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it needed removing as well! You just have to change the regex. It is easy if there is ALWAYS a minus sign: just add the minus sign to the replacement expression, in front of `\\1`. It is slightly less easy if the minus sign is not always there. In that case you want to match it in the first capturing group, which becomes `(-?[0-9]+)`. This means "maybe a minus sign" followed by "at least one number (from 0 to 9)". Now that the minus sign is inside the parenthesis, it is part of the first grouping group so will be added by `\\1`. I'll just edit that in the answer.

Comment: And don't forget (like I just did) to escape the minus sign, because otherwise it has a special meaning in a regex. Always use `\\-` instead of `-` if you mean a literal minus sign.

Comment: I know regex seem daunting at first, but it is a skill really worth learning. Using this sort of websites helps a lot at first: https://regexr.com/4bhon In particular, you can hover on the pattern to see what is going on and you see the matches in real time.

Comment: Beautifully explained, thank you! And thanks for the regex link.